# Selenide: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden"

Tags: kotlin

When trying to run the test, an error occurs. as I understand it, the problem lies in the new chrome, which does not want to work properly with selenide. Error: "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden". How can i fix this problem? Trying it on kotlin

```
class test {

    @Test
    fun testGoogle() {

        page("https://www.google.ru") {
            field(".//textarea[@title='Поиск']") {
                click()
                typeText("izi")
            }
            field(".//input@value='Поиск в Google']") {
                isVisible()
                click()
            }
            field(".//span(text()='info.kz']") {
                isVisible()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Searchpage {

    var searchInput = element(By.xpath(".//textarea[@title='Поиск']"))

    var searchButton = element(By.xpath(".//input[@value='Поиск в Google']"))

    fun typeSearchText(text: String) {
        searchInput.sendKeys(text)
    }

    fun clickSearchButton() {
        searchButton.click()
    }
}

class SearchResultPage {

    var firstResult = element(By.xpath(".//span[text()='info.kz']"))

    fun getFirstResultText():String {
        return firstResult.text()
    }
}

class Page {

}

fun page(url: String, init: Page.() -> Unit): Page {
    open(url)
    return Page().apply(init)
}
class Field(locator: String) {
    private var element: SelenideElement

    init {
        element = element(By.xpath(locator))
    }

    fun typeText(text: String) {
        element.shouldBe(Condition.visible)
        element.sendKeys(text)
    }

    fun click() {
        element.click(ClickOptions.usingJavaScript())
    }

    fun isVisible() {
        element.shouldBe(Condition.visible)
    }
}

fun field(locator: String, action: Field.() -> Unit): Field {
    val field = Field(locator)
    field.apply(action)
    return field
}
```

Tried to get previous version of chrome, but it didn't work